# onClick function to get array from different php file

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to get array from new.php file into index.php via ajax function

```
function retrieve() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'new.php',       
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',    
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
}
```

In new.php I get array from sql query.

```
while ($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $port_list[] = $row['port_name'];

}
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($port_list);
```

and in `index.php` I have `$list = $_POST['$port_list'];`

How can I get values from different PHP file into another without using `session, cookies, form..?`

Comment: when I am using session I need to refresh page to get the results. I would like to show array without refreshing

Comment: The `data` variable in your ajax function should contain the array from `new.php`. So what is the problem?

Comment: something like  data : {port_list:port_list}  ???

Comment: the problem is I don't get any data/array in index.php from $_POST.

Comment: I think you get the concept wrong. In PHP `$_POST` contains data **send** to the server (by a form or trough ajax). When you use ajax, the `data` variable is to **receive** output from your PHP file. POST-data is erased as soon as the php-script ends, so it cannot be passed to another file. Unless you store it in a session (serverside), a cookie (client side) or a javascript variable (client side).

Comment: is there any other way how can I achieve sending this array? or is there anything what I can use in session, as I mention before..without refreshing page ?

Comment: Maybe you could post a little bit more code and exactly what you want to achieve, because there are lots of ways to retrieve data from the server, or include it in other PHP scripts

Comment: `function myAjax() {
var range = document.getElementById('range').value;
var port = document.getElementById('port').value;
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'new.php',
       data:{action:'call_this',range:range,port:port},
       success:function(html) {
        // alert(html);
       }
  });
}

function wait() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'nova2.php',       
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json', //data format      
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}` First function onClick send values to new.php

Comment: In new.php `$query2 = $con->query("SELECT ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$lng') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance, port_name FROM ports HAVING distance < '".$range."' ORDER BY distance;  ");   
while ($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $port_list[] = $row['port_name'];
           }
//$_SESSION["var_name"] = $port_list;
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($port_list);
exit;` The result is array of ports in range of set kilometers. And now I woul like to send this array back to index

Comment: and then I have `var input = <?php echo json_encode($my_var); ?>;` $my_var is this port array and then compare it and colour cells green if the match `if (input.indexOf(args.e.port_name) > -1)  
                        {
                          args.e.backColor = 'green'; 
                                                 }
                       else  {}`

Comment: OK, for clarity: `var input2 = <?php echo json_encode($my_var); ?>; ` is in `index.php`? And you want to send them to `new.php` to use in your query?

Comment: yes var input is in index.php. And I want to GET array from new.php NOT send. I want to return result from new.php to index.php.

Comment: or can I get session value without refreshing page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,
In your index.php file

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="retrieve();">Retrieve</a>
<script>
function retrieve() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'new.php',       
        data: {action:'retrieve'}, //you can use action to validate request
        dataType: 'json',    
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); ///check browser console to see output
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And in new.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'retrieve')
{
    $query == 'select * from tablename';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $resultArr = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $resultArr[] = $row;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArr); 
    die;    
}
?>
```

Comment: no error..check logs and nothing there..somehow it doesnt get array from echo json_encode($resultArr) when I use alert(data), nothing show up.

Comment: @Burco put this code at the top of new.php and see the o/p `echo json_encode("mydata");  die;`

Answer (score -1):

**file1.php:-**

$x1="first";

**file2.php:-**

$x2="second";

**new.php:-**

include 'file1.php';

include 'file2.php';

$all=array( $x1, $x2);

print_r($all);

Comment: OP asked for an ajax-function.

Comment: This is not an ajax function